# Allowing DLL download in IIS7

Tags: iis, activex, handlers

We are using IIS7, currently in classic mode. We have an ActiveX control on our site that needs a DLL to get downloaded to Client. To allow this to happen, we are removing the Execute permission for the DLLs and EXEs (in Handler Mappings).

The problem is that this method prevents any DLL or EXE from being used by the web application. Is there any way to configuring IIS such that a specific DLL can get downloaded, without a blanket removal of Execute permission?

Answer (score 0):

Make another application, in which the handler mapping execute permissions are removed. Store the content in this application and redirect the users to this application.